# Delete lines in a txt file via a batch file until a sequence is found

Tags: batch-file

I have a generated txt file. This file has certain lines that are superfluous, and need to be removed. I need to delete all lines until I find the sequence "AA BB CC DD" that I am looking for and stop deleting and save as a new file.

So, if the txt file looks like this:

```
Good Line of data
bad line of C:\Directory\ERROR\myFile.dll
Another good line of data
bad line: REFERENCE 
AA BB CC DD THis is the start of valid data
Line 2
Line 3
End
```

I would like the new file to end up like this:

```
AA BB CC DD THis is the start of valid data
Line 2
Line 3
End
```

TIA.

Comment: What have you already tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "output="
SET "string=AA BB CC DD"
(
FOR /f "USEBACKQdelims=" %%a IN ("c:\batch scripts\q22188484.txt") DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED output (ECHO %%a|FIND "%string%" >NUL&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET output=Y)
 IF DEFINED output ECHO(%%a
)
)>"newfile.txt"

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22188484.txt` for my testing; output in `newfile.txt`

---

Fix : to allow spaces in the fiename, need quotes but also needs the `USEBACKQ` option. `newfile` modified similarly to suit.

Comment: Hi Magoo, Just tried it. The output file newfile.txt has no output when I paste the sample data into q22188484.txt.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Did you cut-and-paste or retype? Batch can be sensitive to stray spaces for instance, or can be reformatted by an editor trying to be helpful (and assuming that you are creating a WP document.) The match is case-sensitive.

Comment: I copy pasted the code and saved it as a .bat file.. It only generates a blank newfile.txt for me. Wondering why..

Comment: Well, 'tis a mystery - no doubt with a simple explanation. If you comment-out the opening `(` and the `)>newfile.txt` with a `REM ` keyword then the procedure's output should appear on-screen. If you also comment-out the `@echo off` then the operation should appear line-by-line. Perhaps that will yield a clue.

Comment: This is what I see when i run this from cmd promp in the txt file if REM the ECHO OFF
C:\Batch Scripts>(
IF NOT DEFINED output (ECHO C:\Batch Scripts\q22188484.txt  | FIND "AA BB CC DD"  1>NUL  & IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET output=Y )  
 IF DEFINED output ECHO(C:\Batch Scripts\q22188484.txt 
)

Comment: C:\Batch Scripts>a.bat

C:\Batch Scripts>REM @ECHO OFF

C:\Batch Scripts>SETLOCAL

C:\Batch Scripts>SET "output="

C:\Batch Scripts>SET "string=AA BB CC DD"

C:\Batch Scripts>(FOR /F "delims=" %a IN ("C:\Batch Scripts\q22188484.txt") DO (

IF NOT DEFINED output (ECHO %a  | FIND "AA BB CC DD"  1>NUL  & IF NOT ERRORLEVEL
 1 SET output=Y )
 IF DEFINED output ECHO(%a
) ) 1>newfile.txt
C:\Batch Scripts>GOTO :EOF
C:\Batch Scripts>

Comment: Heh - you made one change - substituting the full filename. And guess what - that's the cause of your problem. `for /f ... ("something") ...` parses the literal string `something` so the target string wasn't found, hence no output. Easy fix - I'll amend the batch.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the lines from `where it matches the string` and up to `99999 lines after it`, which in most cases will be until the end.  Add another 9 to that number for nearly 1 million lines.

The search term is a regular expression so if you use certain characters then they may need escaping with `\`

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
type "file.txt"|findrepl "AA BB CC DD"  /o:0:99999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "filename=C:\Batch Scripts\File Name.txt"
for /F "usebackq delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"AA BB CC DD" "%filename%"') do set "line=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
(for /F "usebackq skip=%line% delims=" %%a in ('findstr "^" "%filename%"') do echo %%a) > newFile.txt
```

Comment: you could replace the second `for` construct with `more +%a% %filename% > newfile.txt`